# How can I transform variadic template argument pack to pack with different types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Overall problem being solved:

System with many types of messages being passed around at different rates (ROS). In order to calculate certain statistics it is useful to collect a subset of the messages. The messages are a time-series information, so they need to be collected for some period of time then passed to the function calculating some statistic. In order to simplify the usage of the library I opted to have a class into which I can shove arbitrary types of messages, but to avoid storing large messages I only want to store relevant information, which the user can define on their own. The code below is my attempt at deducing the user defined types through the lambda functions they would supply in order to collect the data they interested in.

I have a class that can hold instances of different types as long as I specify them ahead of time:

```
HeterogenousContainer<A,B,C> hc;
hc.access<A>().push_back(A());
hc.access<B>().push_back(B());
```

In order to get the instances to be stored the original inputs will go through transformation functions results of which will go into the container above.

The transformation functions are supplied through a list of lambdas. What I am trying to do is deduce the return types of the lambdas and then initialize my container with those types:

```
template<typename... Ts>
auto create_aggregator(Ts... lambdas)
{
    ...
    HeterogeneousContainer<typename std::result_of<Ts>::type...> hc;
    ...
}
```

The compiler produces the following error:

> implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::result_of<(lambda at :318:19)>

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You may want to give more info about why you want a Heterogeneous container in first place. Why can't you have various vectors stored in a class?

Comment: `std::result_of<Ts>::type...` - and the `lambdas...` of types `Ts...` are called with...? By example: if you want call them without arguments, you have to write `std::result_of<Ts()>::type...`.

Comment: @max66 That still does not work.

Comment: @NindzAI - It's a pity. Because if you don't show a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's very difficult for other people help you.

Comment: If you are passing in a lambda, then Ts would be a ClosureType. In that case, in your result_of check, you should do something like std::result_of<std::declval<Ts>()>::type if the lambdas have an empty parameter list (i.e. they don't take any arguments)